# database sync using zumero through sql server views

Tags: zumero

I have set up Zumero Server and have added a number of tables a view to my test database. When I open Zumero Manager I can select the tables to prepare but not the view. Does this mean that Zumero does not support syncing through views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Zumero syncs tables (or selected portions of tables), not views.